# Probability Question Regarding Selection of Committees...

Tags: probability

A committee of $3$ students is to be chosen from the following table:

[image]

I need to know:

- How many committees of $3$ students are possible?
- How many possible committees contain at least one member of each sex?
- How many ways to select one student from each stage?

---

I know that there are $84$ or $\left( \matrix{9 \hfill \cr 3 \hfill \cr}  \right)$ ways to select $3$ out of $9$ students.

I know the last part, selecting from each stage is $\left( \matrix{
  3 \hfill \cr 
  1 \hfill \cr}  \right) \times \left( \matrix{
  4 \hfill \cr 
  1 \hfill \cr}  \right) \times \left( \matrix{
  2 \hfill \cr 
  1 \hfill \cr}  \right) = 24$ different ways.

I do not know how to solve the second part.

It seems it should be $\left( \matrix{
  5 \hfill \cr 
  1 \hfill \cr}  \right) \times \left( \matrix{
  4 \hfill \cr 
  1 \hfill \cr}  \right) \times 1 = 20$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The $\times 1$ is wrong. Having selected a female and a male there are 7 ways to select the 3rd member. But the problem then is that you have double counted. So it is easier to deduct from 84 the number of all male and all female committees.

Comment: Why is it you have double counted? I clearly see you have but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Suppose you select A as a female, then B as a male, then F as the 3rd member. But you might also select F as the female, B as the male and then A as the 3rd member.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your method for part 2 *under* counts.

A way to correctly count is add the counts of committees with $2M,1F$ and $1M,2F$, viz

$\binom42\binom51 + \binom41\binom52$

Comment: Why does my method double count? I see that it does but I don't know why.

Comment: Sorry, it *under* counts. Suppose you chose $AC$ using $\binom51\binom41.$ There are *many* choices left for the third person, but you have multiplied by $1$.